# Why doesn't the CSS style apply to my div and class combination?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

My files are as follows. The class/div only inherit from the main body file, and I'm not sure why. How exactly do I need to format the CSS to make the styling work correctly?
The files are linked correctly, but the form still doesn't show a stylized version. Buttons work fine, only the list is broken.

```
/* Style the list items */
#add_step_item > form > ul > li{
      cursor: pointer;
      position: relative;
      padding: 12px 8px 12px 40px;
      font-size: 18px;
      transition: 0.2s;
}

/* Set all odd list items to a different color (zebra-stripes) */
#add_step_item > form > ul > li:nth-child(odd) {
      background: #f9f9f9;
}

  /* Darker background-color on hover */
#add_step_item > form > ul > li:hover {
      background: #ddd;
}

  /* When clicked on, add a background color and strike out text */
#add_step_item > form > ul > li.checked {
      background: #888;
      color: #fff;
      text-decoration: line-through;
}

  /* Add a "checked" mark when clicked on */
#add_step_item > form > ul > li.checked::before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      border-color: #fff;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
      top: 10px;
      left: 16px;
      transform: rotate(45deg);
      height: 15px;
      width: 7px;
}
```

Index.haml

```
- if @user.teacher?
  #add_step_item
    = form_for '', :remote => true do |f|
      %input{:name => "fixed_date", :type => "hidden", :value => ""}
      %input{:name => "student_id", :type => "hidden", :value => @student.id}
      %input{:name => "description", :type => "hidden", :value => "このステップをやり直してください！"}
      %input{:name => "difficulty", :type => "hidden", :value => "0"}
      %h1 弱点
      %ul
        %li With a class attached,
        %li I can style this one
        %li differently than others.
      %button{:type => "button", :value => "キャンセル"} キャンセル
      %button{:type => "submit", :value => "addstep"} 追加する
      %button{:type => "submit", :value => "change"} 変更する
```

Comment: in your CSS you have `#add_task_item` and in the haml it's `#add_step_item`, is that a typo while minimizing the example or that way in your code?

Comment: @SimpleLime that's a typo. I fixed it but the problem still persists.

Comment: What's the name of the CSS file you gave us there? Are you depending on multiple CSS files to style your application?

Comment: @MarsAtomic Yes, there are multiple css files. The one shown above is edit.css. It's inheriting from body.css it seems.

Comment: When you say "the files are linked correctly" what, exactly, do you mean? It sounds like you're expecting CSS files to override one another depending on load order, but the Rails Asset Pipeline precludes that type of setup unless you make specific changes to match CSS files to specific views.

Comment: If you are on Chrome, please use Developer's console (F12) to inspect which css is being applied, if your css is loaded at all or being overriden by another css files.

Comment: to complete Fazley comment, there is a similar set of tools in firefox with ctrl+shift+k